# Правильно ли использование "него" или "его" или изменить предложение?

Tags: стилистика

> Нельзя было найти человека, знавшего хадисы Посланника Аллаха саллаллаху алайхи васаллам лучше него или лучше него понимавшего вопросы фикха.

Мое предположение:

1. Может все таки лучше его?
2. Или изменить предложение: `Нельзя было найти человека знавшего хадисы Посланника Аллаха саллаллаху алайхи васаллам, и понимавшего вопросы фикха лучше его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Выбираем форму "лучше его":** Нельзя было найти человека, знавшего хадисы Посланника Аллаха саллаллаху алайхи васаллам **лучше его или лучше его** понимавшего вопросы фикха.

В то же время форма "лучше него" также встречается в текстах.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

**Проблема выбора его/него** связана с тем, что "его" может быть **притяжательным или личным местоимением**: Это **его** книга?  Я сегодня встречу **его** и спрошу **у него**. **Около него** всегда много людей. **Благодаря ему**, я узнал много нового и интересного.

Как можно видеть, начальное Н появляется у **личного местоимения** после непроизводного предлога У, а также производного предлога ОКОЛО, но после предлога БЛАГОДАРЯ начальное Н не используется.

**Вопрос о начальном Н  регулируется правилом, изложенным у Розенталя:** 
[§169. Личные местоимения](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm)

В то же время не всегда можно получить четкий ответ на этот вопрос.

**У Розенталя:** **Не добавляется начальное Н в тех случаях**, когда местоимение стоит **после сравнительной степени прилагательного или наречия**, например: старше его, выше ее, лучше их.

Но в Нацкорпусе  встречаются обе  формы, хотя вариант "лучше его" преобладает, тем не менее   существует мнение, что выбор Н в данном случае факультативен:

Никто **лучше него** не объяснит тебе, что кино ― это «ярмарка тщеславия». [Василий Аксенов. Новый сладостный стиль (2005)]

**Лучше его** никто не рисовал анатомических препаратов. [Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого [Путешествие в седьмую сторону света] // «Новый Мир», 2000]

«Совершенно ясно, что **лучше его** никто не сыграет». [Лидия Вертинская. Синяя птица любви (2004)]

Comment: "Проблема выбора" связана с историческими фонетическими и грамматическими явлениям в русском языке, а не с омнонимичностью  грамматических форм. Плюс заметное непонимание Вами смысла исходного текста. Примеры не по сути.

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. Причина изложена в комментарии.

Answer (score 3):

1. В вашем предложении не совсем ясно, кто такой "он": Аллах, его Посланник или кто-то третий, о ком ранее шла речь. Как я могу догадаться, "он" - это Мухаммед. Чтобы хотя бы частично избежать неоднозначности, я предлагаю говорить "его самого". Тогда остаются только первый и второй вариант, но тут можно положиться на сообразительность читателя.
2. По поводу выбора между "его" и "него" я никаких правил не нашел, кажется оба варианта допустимы. Я поставил "лучше его самого" и "лучше него" просто полагаясь на свое чувство языка.
3. "Нельзя было найти человека" тоже не вполне однозначно (может, этот человек спрятался и его нельзя найти :) ) и немного коряво. Лучше сказать: "Не существовало человека".
4. Не могу судить о правильности написания слов "Посланника Аллаха саллаллаху алайхи васаллам". Оставляю это автору.

Мой вариант:

**Не было человека, знавшего хадисы Посланника Аллаха саллаллаху алайхи васаллам лучше его самого или лучше него понимавшего вопросы фикха.**

Comment: Вы, похоже, слегка запутались в мусульманских реалиях. Никак не "его самого". Речь не может идти о Пророке (с.а. вассалям!). Сам Пророк (с.а. вассалям!) не был факихом (знатоком богословия и мусульманского права), он стоит **над ним**.

Comment: @Мимоходов, Да я в них - полный невежда. Но тогда о ком идет речь, кто такой "он" - непревзойденный знаток хадисов и фикха?

Comment: Да я сам знаток никакой, но всё же...  О каком-то уважаемом факихе, видимо. Это если текст богословский или исторический. А может, о мудреце из соседнего аула. Это обычный для Востока прием выражения почтения в форме превознесения заслуг уважаемого и/или пожилого человека. Тут этакая игра слов на русский слух получается на тему "Неуловимого Джо". Нельзя было найти, потому что никто и не искал. А искать никто и не будет, потому, что это будет признаком неуважения к уважаемому. "Восток - дело тонкое" (С).

Answer (score 0):

"Невозможно было встретить человека, лучше него (по)знавшего хадисы Посланника Аллаха саллаллаху алайхи васаллам и лучше понимавшего вопросы фикха".

Склоняюсь к такому варианту записи фразы.

Answer (score -1):

> использование “него” или “его”

Оба варианта в принципе возможны.

> или изменить предложение?

Да, лучше изменить.

Но я начну с другого.
Авазбек Исманов, для русскоязычного читателя, не знакомого с мусульманской традицией, формулу обращения к Пророку лучше давать в скобках или даже в переводе (последнее - если это не религиозная литература). При этом саму арабскую форма Вики (и не только) рекомендует передавать транскрипцией "Салла-л-Ла́ху алейхи ва саллам".

Это звучало бы примерно так.

*Нельзя было найти человека, знавшего хадисы Посланника Аллаха (Салла-л-Ла́ху алейхи ва саллам!), лучше его или понимавшего вопросы фикха лучше его.*

*Нельзя было найти человека, знавшего хадисы Посланника Аллаха (Мир ему и благословение Аллаха!) лучше его или лучше его понимавшего вопросы фикха.*

Теперь по вашим вопросам. 
Возможно "его" и "него". 
В формах местоимений 3-го лица (н)его, (н)ее и (н)их,  при сравнительных  степенях наращение Н факультативно.
Подробно здесь.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/65-n-mestoimenie

Я рекомендую здесь Еськову вопреки Розенталю уже потому, что это именно её тема и написано много позже, ближе к современности.

Плюс прямой ответ "Справки".

> Вопрос № 222265
>   К вопросу 222220, выдержка из работы Дитмара Розенталя: Не
>   добавляется начальное н в тех случаях, когда местоимение стоит после
>   сравнительной степени прилагательного или наречия, например: старше
>   его, выше её, лучше их.
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Как равноправные варианты *лучше его* и *лучше него* приводятся в
>   «Кратком словаре трудностей русского языка» Н. А. Еськовой.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE

В сочетании с "лучше", судя по Нацкорпусу, много чаще употребляется форма "лучше его", но в вашем случае я бы рекомендовал использование наращения в целях облегчения понимания: во избежание смешения с омонимичной конструкцией *"лучше (бы) его знать"*.

> Или изменить предложение: `Нельзя было найти человека знавшего хадисы
>   Посланника Аллаха саллаллаху алайхи васаллам, и понимавшего вопросы фикха > лучше его.

Такой вариант лучше. Но причина не в использовании формы предлогов, а в том сто в исходном варианте возникает нежелательное для данного текста стечение "лучше (н)его или лучше (н)его". Это было бы приемлемо, будь они разделены запятой, но она тут не предполагается, поскольку причастные обороты выступают как однородные члены.

Мой окончательный вариант.

***Нельзя было найти человека, лучше него знавшего хадисы Посланника Аллаха (Да благословит его Аллах и приветствует!) или понимавшего вопросы фикха лучше него.***

или с формулой на арабском.

***Нельзя было найти человека, лучше него знавшего хадисы Посланника Аллаха (Салла-л-Лаху алейхи ва саллам!) или понимавшего вопросы фикха лучше него.***